# Spark SQL coalesce function fails to evaluate

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, coalesce

I am doing an outer join between a source dataframe and a smaller "overrides" dataframe, and I'd like to use the `coalesce` function:

```
    val outputColumns: Array[Column] = dimensionColumns.map(dc => etlDf(dc)).union(attributeColumns.map(ac => coalesce(overrideDf(ac), etlDf(ac))))
    etlDf.join(overrideDf, childColumns, "left").select(outputColumns:_*)
```

When it comes time to write the resulting dataframe to a parquet file, I am receiving the following exception:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Attribute name "coalesce(top_customer_fg, top_customer_fg)" contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=". Please use alias to rename it.;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetSchemaConverter$.checkConversionRequirement(ParquetSchemaConverter.scala:581)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetSchemaConverter$.checkFieldName(ParquetSchemaConverter.scala:567)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetWriteSupport$$anonfun$setSchema$2.apply(ParquetWriteSupport.scala:431)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetWriteSupport$$anonfun$setSchema$2.apply(ParquetWriteSupport.scala:431)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetWriteSupport$.setSchema(ParquetWriteSupport.scala:431)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat.prepareWrite(ParquetFileFormat.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.writeInFileFormat(DataSource.scala:484)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:520)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:494)
    at com.mycompany.customattributes.ProgramImplementation$StandardProgram.createAttributeFiles(ProgramImplementation.scala:63)
```

So even though the `coalesce` function returns a column, it appears it is evaluated as a literal column name. This seems unexpected to me.

Is there a syntax mistake I'm making here, or do I need to take a different approach?

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't look like an issue with `coalesce` being returned as a literal. How about  `coalesce( overrideDf(ac) , etlDf(ac) ).as(s"${ac}") )`?

Comment: That works, although we just need to pass the column name without any string interpolation: `.as(ac)`, Change this to an answer and I will accept it.